# how to create checkboxes and save their values in database for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, checkbox

I just want to know how do I create checkboxes in template file of wordpress theme and save their values in postmeta table.This is how I created checkboxes like regular html
This is my code for checkboxes

```
<p class="full_form"><label for="prop_category"><?php _e('We are into','wpestate');?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="architecture" size="80" name="ckb" value="<?php print 
 $architecture;?>">Architecture
        <input type="checkbox" id="builder_developer" size="80" name="ckb" value="<?php print
  $builder_developer;?>">Builders and Developeres
        <input type="checkbox" id="material_supplier" size="80" name="ckb" value="<?php print
   $material_supplier;?>">Material Supplier
        <input type="checkbox" id="contractor" size="80" name="ckb" value="<?php print
   $contractor;?>">Contractor
        <input type="checkbox" id="int_decorator" size="80" name="ckb" value="<?php print

  $int_decorator;?>">Interior Decorator
        <input type="checkbox" id="prop_finance" size="80" name="ckb" value="<?php print
   $prop_finance;?>">Property Finance
        <input type="checkbox" id="prop_legal_ad" size="80" name="ckb" value="<?php print
   $prop_legal_ad;?>">Property Legal Advisor
        <input type="checkbox" id="prop_valuer" size="80" name="ckb" value="<?php print
   $prop_valuer;?>">Property Valuer
        <input type="checkbox" id="vastu_consult" size="80" name="ckb" value="<?php print
   $vastu_consult;?>">Vaastu Consultant
   </p>
```

Comment: where is this form located? This is for admin or all site users.

Comment: You try $_REQUEST['ckb'] and insert into database.
Please explain your question briefly

Comment: This is for site users...

Comment: then use get_user_meta($user_id,'your_key',$_REQUEST['ckb']);

Comment: you checked user_id comes or not and values saved in DB or not